# LZ78 algorithm - overwriting dictionary after filling dictionary?

Tags: c, compression

I have a question about methods of implementation LZ78 algorithm - is there any possibility to add new 'keywords' after filling dictionary to first indexes? Look at my code:

```
//adding new word to dictionary
int dodaj(unsigned char *dop )
{
  int i;
  slownik[ adresy[ilosc]*257 ] = dop[0];
  for(i=1;i<dop[0]+1;i++)
    slownik[ adresy[ilosc]*257+i ] = dop[i];
  ilosc++;
  if( ilosc>ROZMIAR-1 ) przesun();
}

//move location in dictionary, if full
int przesun()
{
  int i,b;
  b = adresy[0];
  for( i=0; i<ROZMIAR-1; i++ )
  {
    adresy[i] = adresy[i+1];
  }
  adresy[ ROZMIAR-1] = b;
  ilosc--;
}
```

In my code, after filling dictionary, all occurrences are moved -1, last one is overwriten. Do you guys have any ideas how to modify this code?

Answer (score 0):

This loop, if we start with `adresy` containing `a, b, c, d` and `ROZMIAR=4` will result in:

for( i=0; i

`adresy` containing `b, b, b, b`.

I suspect you want to start from the top and walk down?

I have to note tho' that I don't fully understand your code, and I find it hard to read code where variables sort of look like names, but I can't understand what they mean.

Comment: Let's say, the adresy[] array begin with small eneries - 4 signs then empty 253 spaces. I want to put there, in those empty spaces next words, as much, as dictionary could have.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure my answer explains that - you have to start at the highest [used] address.